# How to Create google map polyline from gps points?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have a collection of gps points in the following format:

> S 25°35', W 48°10'

I cannot find a way to pass it to google maps api (v2) , so that I can draw a polyline.

Comment: @user421061 Let us know if there is anything in our answers that we need to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is convert the degree-style latitude and longitude into a decimal style geo location point. Then you'll have the style that google is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your degrees, minutes, seconds location into a decimal location:

```
// For 25°35'0''
var degrees = 25;
var minutes = 35;
var seconds = 0;

// need to calculate the decimal 25.5833333
var longitude = degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 60 / 60);
```